# Tests failed when run several test projects simultaneously

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, resharper

Suppose I have 5 test projects in my solution, each of them have some test cases.
When I ran project individually, all cases in that project got passed.
When I ran projects as a whole, then a lot of test cases in 3 projects failed.
The error message shows that the failed test case can't find some settings in web.config which does exist.
When do a daily build in TFS, some of test cases will fail either, but much less.
All the cases are faking unit test without real database query or network traffic.

ENV: NUnit 2.6.3, vs 2013 premium , resharper 8.2.3 full edition.

Comment: The relevant information is what those tests do. If they don't work together but do work if run separately, they are in fact changing global state. Anything static is a candidate for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests probably leak into each other. Perhaps review the initialize and cleanup and the general state of each test class.

Note that you may have initialize and cleanup and method level, class level and assembly level and they all state.

Comment: I find out that it's caused by resharper.

resharper->options->Tools->Unit Testing->check 'Use separate AppDomain for each assembly with tests'